# GUI program to record internet radio with songs tags (title, artist, etc.)?

Tags: gui, internet-radio, audio-recording, tag

In Windows I like Screamer Radio, and I know that are others like RarmaRadio, programs which can record radio music and also save the proper titles, artist names, etc.

Is there such a program in Ubuntu?

---

I am looking for a native linux program, but Wine-based solutions are welcomed as a second choice. I will also try Wine myself and provide an answer.

Also, although I am looking for a program that would record songs with tag names, I am not aware of a Linux program that can record radio songs **separately (split)** even without tag names and titles. - So, a such program may deserve to be mentioned too.

Another basic desirable features that need mentioning are:

- playing songs while recording
- large database of stations
- possibility of adding new stations
- recording multiple stations at the same time

---

I have posted a complementary answer limited to the use of Windows programs in Wine. I expect a definitive answer on a native program. But **I'll accept that as definitive only if the solutions proposed are at least as good as those accessible through Wine**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [StreamTuner2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamtuner2/files/) with [Streamripper (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/streamripper/) ([Install streamripper](https://hostmar.co/software-small)) to record Online Radio Streams.

To Grap Streamripper in terminal just do this:

```
sudo apt-get install streamripper
```

Streamripper and streamtuner2 are Linux applications that work in tandem, allowing you to listen and record streaming radio.

Streamtuner2 is a basic application used primarily for playing internet radio from any number of sources including *Xiph, basic.ch, punkcast.com, Google Stations, Live365, and SHOUTcast*. It will use `streamripper` to record and an external player to play a stream.

[image]

Streamtuner2 can add favourite stations to bookmarks. New stations can be added by selecting some station, right-click, Edit, 'New', and, after setting a new name and URL, OK and then Reload button.

Clicking the play button after selecting a station will start the radio station in external player. The same happens when double-clicking a station in a list.

Clicking the record button after selecting a station will run `streamripper` in a terminal window and by default each track will be saved separately in the Home folder.

To set custom folder for recordings in Streamtuner2, under 'Edit-Properties-Recording application', edit the line under 'Application' by adding `-d path_to_folder` at the end (like `x-terminal-emulator -e streamripper %srv -d /home/user/Audio/Recordings`). There can be added many other custom commands that `streamripper` allows - see below on more options.

Search function doesn’t work as it should.

To save in a custom folder by using just streamripper in a terminal (CLI, without Streamtuner), open the terminal in that folder.

Multiple instances of streamripper (that is recording of multiple tracks) can be run at the same time in separate terminal windows.

[image]

On more options in Streamripper there are  [Ubuntu Guide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Streamripper), [Reference](http://myubuntutech.blogspot.in/2009/05/how-to-record-streaming-net-radio-in.html),[Tutorial](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/tutorialconsole.php), [Ubuntu Man Page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/streamripper.1.html), [My Ubuntu Blogspot](http://myubuntutech.blogspot.in/2009/05/how-to-record-streaming-net-radio-in.html).

Streamripper sits stealthily in the terminal recording and parsing all of the music piped through your system into MP3s. Leaving Streamripper running all day will rack you up a healthy dose of your favorite tunes. By itself `streamripper` is able to record streams with the command:

```
$ streamripper <URL>
```

What is particularly nice about the combination of Streamripper and streamtuner2 is that once you choose a station to record, you can exit streamtuner2 leaving only a tiny, non-obtrusive terminal window for Streamripper.

Answer (score 4):

This complementary answer is limited to the use of Windows programs in Wine. I expect a definitive answer on a native program.

---

My favorites in Windows are **RadioSure, Screamer Radio** and **RarmaRadio**. I have tried to install them in **Playonlinux** but they don't work. Some tweaking with Wine settings or versions may fix them but that's beyond my ability.

After testing most of the programs mentioned [here](http://listoffreeware.com/list-of-best-free-internet-radio-recorder/) and [here](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/pictures-story/435-10-internet-radio-recording.html), I ended up with 3 programs working in Playonlinux.

[image]

**TapinRadio:**

[image]

- can play while recording - YES
- records separately - YES
- has a large database - YES
- can add new stations - YES
- can save tags – YES
- can record only one station at a time

**StreamWriter :**

[image]

- can play while recording - YES
- records separately - YES
- has a large database - YES
- can add new stations - YES
- can save tags – YES (needs custom settings - see below)
- can record multiple stations simultaneously

**StationRipper:**

[image]

- can play while recording – NO (normally yes, but not in Wine)
- records separately - YES
- has a large database – NO (normally yes, it should access Shoutcast, but that doesn't work in Wine)
- can add new stations - YES
- can save tags – YES
- can record 2 stations simultaneously in the free version

---

I mention **StationRipper** just for reference - but I don't recommend it in Linux/Wine.

The other two work great.

**TapinRadio** is very easy to use and straightforward out of the box; it can record only one station at a time and save the track as mp3, wma, aac and ogg.

**StreamWriter** has more features: it can record multiple streams at the same time, can schedule recording of specific station, tracks, artists, etc. It can convert to mp3, aac and ogg, or it can avoid changing format. Two issues need attention though:

- the tags-saving feature is disabled by default for some reason. So, enable it under 'File-Settings-Posprocessing' and in 'File-Settings for automatic recordings-Posprocessing'. The fully tagged file will be saved in a separate folder at the end of each track. During recording the incomplete file will not be tagged.
- recording works only if the path to the folder to save songs starts with `C:`

[image]

Changing that to `Z:` gives an error on lacking disk space.

Comment: Excellent cipricus. I've always used StreamRipper in Windows, but have found your advise today and installed Wine, PlayOnLinux, and StreamWriter and followed your instructions. Great stuff!

Comment: @AndyPyne - thanks for remembering me about this - I have re-installed it myself, and I also prefer it to the Linux native solution, whose answer needs updating anyway I think.

Answer (score 1):

The Exaile music player for a long time has had the ability to use Streamripper built-in. Just install Exaile and Streamripper, then enable it in the preferences gui of Exaile,you'll find it with all the other plugins. That's it, just hit the record button while listening to your favorite radio station.